# jQuery selector all elements not in subclass

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this HTML (can be different) somewhere on the page:

```
<div id="start">
<div>
    <div class="buttons">select this</div>
    <div class="myControl">
        <div class="buttons">dont select this</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="buttons">select this</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>​
```

I want to mark all elements with class `buttons` red:

```
$('#start').find('.buttons').css('color','red');​
```

but **not** if they are inside of `myControl`, so only the "select this" divs should be red.

In pseudocode the selector would be

> Take every element with class "buttons" but ignore everything 
>   in elements with class "myControl"

I prepared a **[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/QqRuV/)**.

---

**EDIT**

I wasn't aware of the fact that the start div can have the "myControl" class as well (tried to strip down the code from my project as far as possible to make it readable), so actually it looks like this (and the complete block could be nested in more divs with myControl as well).

So unfortunately the (correct for my original question) answers doesn't work in that situation, sorry for that! Any idea how to tweak one of the answers to solve this?

```
<div class="myControl" id="start">
<div>
    <div class="buttons">select this</div>
    <div class="myControl">
        <div class="buttons">dont select this</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="buttons">select this</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>​
```

The [**new jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/QqRuV/8/).

---

**SOLUTION**

So the final solution was this:

```
$('#start').find('.buttons:not("#start div.myControl div.buttons ")')
.css('color','red');​
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use .not

```
 $('#start').find('.buttons:not("div.myControl > div.buttons ")').css('color','red');​
```

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QqRuV/3/

Comment: This is a great solution, unfortunaly it doesn't work if the buttons are not direct children of myControl... do you have an idea how to fix that? Here is your forked and changed jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/QqRuV/5/

Comment: then use like this $('#start').find('.buttons:not("div.myControl div.buttons ")').css('color','red');​ i have updated jsfiddle .
http://jsfiddle.net/QqRuV/6/

Comment: A single selector version of this would be `$(#start  .buttons:not(.myControl  .buttons))`

Comment: Thank you so much guys and I'm so sorry, the outer div can be of class `myControl` as well which makes it not working (its in my project, wasn't aware of that)... So any chance to solve this as well? I hope it is the last change... :/ http://jsfiddle.net/marcgrabow/QqRuV/7/

Comment: use outer element id with not selector.`$('#start').find('.buttons:not("#start div.myControl div.buttons ")').css('color','red');​`.please find the jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QqRuV/10/

Comment: You're awesome, thanks a lot! +1! I really should learn a bit more about selectors...

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#start').find('.buttons').filter(function(e) { return $(this).parent(".myControl").length < 1; }).css('color','red');​
```

Comment: Good solution to use a filter function (wasn't aware of that) but I'm a bit worried about the performance?

Comment: Actually I think the framework will do something simillar to this no matter what method you choose to go with (not sure, just guessing). For readability however I think YogeshWaran's solution with not() is a bit better. Comes down to taste I guess :) GL

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#start').children('.buttons').css('color', 'red')
```

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't work because the buttons are not direct children of the parent.